# Rotate the appWidgetIds continuously with time

Tags: android, kotlin, widget

I am creating the clock widget in my app. I want to rotate the needle with time. I have tried different ways but have not been successful yet. If I don't apply any method to rotate the widget appears [erfactly, but as I apply any thy to it like in my code I use setFloat() method there appears the text "Loading problem" in place of the widget. I am sharing my code, please help me out in rotating the needles.
This is the XML of clock_widget

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clockFace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hourHand"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/hour_1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/minuteHand"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/minute_1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the AppWidgetProvider class for my clock widget:

````
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Matrix
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import java.util.Calendar

class ClockWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context?,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray?
    ) {
        appWidgetIds?.let {
            for (appWidgetId in it) {
                // Get the current time
                val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                val hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)
                val minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
              

                // Calculate rotation angles
                val hourRotation = hour * 30f
                val minuteRotation = minute * 6.0f
              

                // Create RemoteViews
                val views = RemoteViews(context?.packageName, R.layout.clock_widget)

                // Update rotation angles for the clock hands
                views.setFloat(R.id.hourHand, "setRotation", hourRotation)
                views.setFloat(R.id.minuteHand, "setRotation", minuteRotation)
              
                // Update the App Widget
                appWidgetManager?.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)

            }
        }
    }

} ```
````